# Spark Streaming : Reading data from kafka that has multiple schema

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, apache-spark-dataset

I am struggling with the implementation in spark streaming.

The messages from the kafka looks like this but with with more fields

```
{"event":"sensordata", "source":"sensors", "payload": {"actual data as a json}}
{"event":"databasedata", "mysql":"sensors", "payload": {"actual data as a json}}
{"event":"eventApi", "source":"event1", "payload": {"actual data as a json}}
{"event":"eventapi", "source":"event2", "payload": {"actual data as a json}}
```

I am trying to read the messages from a Kafka topic (which has multiple schemas). I need to read each message and look for an event and source field and decide where to store as a Dataset. The actual data is in the field payload as a JSON which is only a single record.

Can someone help me to implement this or any other alternatives?

Is it a good way to send the messages with multiple schemas in the same topic and consume it?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: can you try if producer can send each message at a time..then you can parse this string to jsonString and will get key and values.

Comment: Are you using avro schema? If so, avro has schema evolution which will solve your problem. If not, then try to use avro schema.

Comment: @Nilesh Yeah, I can get the key value after parsing, but how do I create a dataset from that parsed data and store it somewhere, It contains only a single record in that message.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `Dataframe` from the incoming JSON object.

Create `Seq[Sring]` of JSON object.

Use val `df=spark.read.json[Seq[String]]`.

Perform the operations on the `dataframe df` of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Converting JsonString to `JavaBean` if you only care about some columns

Comment: I can get the payload field which is the exact data that i needed, but how do i separate these message as per their case class?